# protobuf implementation for iOS and server

Tags: ios, protocol-buffers

I plan to use protobuf on both iOS and server side to take care of data models. I choose google protobuf compiler to generate java models on server side and use objective-c protobuf plugin compiler to generate objective models on iOS side.

I have the following questions, and hope someone can help.

1. How to handle networking layer? What's the content-type for sending data to client ? I found some experts suggest "application/octet-stream" and some suggest application/x-protobuf.
2. How can I use AFNetworking lib on client side.
3. Is there sample project for iOS-server protobuf implementation?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  1. That's a good question.  2. That question is too broad.  Read the documentation and come back with specific questions about problems you have.  3.  Questions asking us to recommend off-site tutorials and examples, etc, are off-topic.  Searching github may be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for comments. question is not about protobuf itself.  if anyone can give me some suggestions on architecture level , that will help.

Comment: I've implemented protobuf in swift and objc and its backend in golang. Refer https://github.com/alexeyxo/protobuf-swift & https://github.com/alexeyxo/protobuf-objc. I'll try uploading the sample project this weekend.

Comment: Hi, kumar. is sample project available somewhere? expect to see it. thanks.

Comment: Hi, kumar. For alex protobuf-obj github, I checkout master branch and try to build /Example/iOS/Proto.xcodeproj. However, I got error :Descriptor.pb.h:  lexical or Preprocessor Issue "ProtocolBuffers/ProtocolBuffers.h" file not found. I tried to configure header search paths, and still does not work. Any suggestions about this issue? I use code 6.4. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following RPC framework built on protocol buffers: http://www.grpc.io/

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question. How can I use AFNetworking to post my protobuf data?
I write these code:

```
NSMutableData *protubufData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
// 0XFF
int str = 0xff;
str = htonl(str);
[protubufData appendBytes:&str length:sizeof(str)];
// playerId
long playerId = 86966;
playerId = htonll(playerId);
NSData *playerIdData = [NSData dataWithBytes: &playerId length: sizeof(playerId)];
[protubufData appendData:playerIdData];
// sessionId
long sessionId = 1789586966;
sessionId = htonll(sessionId);
NSData *sessionIdData = [NSData dataWithBytes: &sessionId length: sizeof(sessionId)];
[protubufData appendData:sessionIdData];

int commandId = 17895;
commandId = htonl(commandId);
// size
u_long size = params.length+4;
size = htonl(size);
[protubufData appendBytes:&size length:4];
// commandId
NSData *commandIdData = [NSData dataWithBytes: &commandId length: sizeof(commandId)];
[protubufData appendData:commandIdData];
// data
[protubufData appendData:params];
```

I use AFN method:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                parameters:(id)parameters
                  progress:(void (^)(NSProgress * _Nonnull))uploadProgress
                   success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull, id _Nullable))success
                   failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable, NSError * _Nonnull))failure
```

but the protobuf data being received is not what is expected !

then I use NSURLConnection.  Abandoned AFN !

```
//Step One
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:baseProUrl];
//Step Two
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:protubufData];
//Step Three
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

//Step Four
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
NSHTTPURLResponse *res = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
NSLog(@"%@",[res allHeaderFields]);
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
NSData *prodata = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(12, data.length)];
VickyTest_Req *req = [VickyTest_Req parseFromData:prodata error:nil];
NSLog(@"req:%@",req);
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Finally succeed!